# Как можно это распараллелить или ускорить

Tags: c#, .net

Есть 2 коллекции.

Коллекция слов и коллекция текста(1 элемент=1 страницы).

Я беру страницу, далее разбиваю ее на слова и занимаюсь перебором через расстояние Левинштейна в попытках найти похожие слова на странице.

Очень долго... Как бы это распаралелить? Если я не ошибаюсь, то итераторы не потокобезопасны => как я понимаю, что бы добиться паралелизма мне придется на каждый поток копировать коллекцию слов?

Comment: итераторы потокобезопасны (относительно друг друга), если вы не меняете исходную коллекцию

Comment: Неоднократно уже на этом сайте советовал книгу [Patterns for Parallel Programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) - там приведён способ распараллеливания алгоритма Левенштейна. Вдруг пригодится.

Comment: @PashaPash, хм... Мне казалось, что нет и MSDN об этом молчит. В таком случае, я могу распараллелить коллекцию слов.

Comment: @iluxa1810 итерирование коллекции через enumerable обычно эту коллекцию не изменяет. если нет изменений - нет и проблем с многопоточностью.